# EXCEL VBA - Make Cells Required

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet and want to make some cells required before they save it and send it back to us.

I have the following code, however the checking wont stop on the specified cells and just continues. What should I do to make it stop on the specified ranges?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
Cancel As Boolean)


    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngLstRow As Long, lngTCols As Long
    Dim lngRowCheck(1 To 2) As String


    lngRowCheck(1) = "B2:B18"
    lngRowCheck(2) = "D2:D4"



    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


    For i = 1 To UBound(lngRowCheck)
        For Each rngCell In Range(lngRowCheck(i) & "2:" & lngRowCheck(i) & lngLstRow)
            If rngCell.Value = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Address)
                rngCell.Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: try the code in my answer below and let me know if that's what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Union` to merge your searched ranges, by that you can take out the `For` loop, and your code will be cleaner ans easier to understand.
Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long, lngTCols As Long
Dim lngRowCheck(1 To 2) As String

lngRowCheck(1) = "B2:B18"
lngRowCheck(2) = "D2:D4"

Dim UnionRng        As Range
Set UnionRng = Application.Union(Range("B2:B18"), Range("D2:D4"))

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each rngCell In UnionRng.Cells
    If rngCell.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Address)
        rngCell.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai it's working now. :) exactly what i mean.